# Registering a GCM Service on Android in Application Class

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Would it be a good idea to register GCM in an Application class like so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

      private GCMRegistrationUtil mGCMRegistrationUtil = GCMRegistrationUtil.getInstance(this);

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          String registrationId = mGCMRegistrationUtil.registerDevice();
          Log.d(TAG, "Device Registered Properly: " + registrationId);
      }
```

It's working fine - I just am wondering if this could create any issues since it's inside an application class. I implemented it this was so it always checks to see if an id is stored in SharedPreferences immediately upon application startup, and if not go ahead and register.

By issues I am guessing maybe Performance issues?? Any potential for that?

Comment: It's ok, but first always get regId from sharedPreferences. Only if stored locally regId is empty (update is happened) you must call registerDevice() method.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing as I mentioned in the post.  GCMRegistrationUtil checks for that